# Resource Governor and Resource Pool CPU Utilization Configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, resource-governor

I have been trying to understand more in-depth how the resource governor resource pool limits work in conjunction with multiple user defined pools.

I've been trying to follow along the table in this MS doc: [Resource Governor Resource Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor-resource-pool?view=sql-server-ver15)

But the formula explanations are a little vague (to my eyes) so I'm trying to make sure I am calculating the effective max and shared % numbers correctly.

[image: Proposed RG Resource Pool Config]

The formulas in the comment column are for calculated effective max. Shared % seems fairly straightforward and dependent on the accuracy of the effective max.  My questions are as follows:

1. Do user defined resource pools consider the default pool in their calculations?  I assumed they do because the default pool (from the MS example) considers the MIN values of user pools for the default pool calculation.
2. Is it nonsensical as I believe for the SUM of all calculated shared % to be >100%?  The MS examples all fall below 100%.
3. Could someone please explain this blurb on shared % from the MS docs, I'm not fully understanding what the shared % calculation is supposed to represent:

> The shared part of the pool is used to indicate where available
> resources can go if resources are available. However, when resources
> are consumed they go to the specified pool and are not shared. This
> may improve resource utilization in cases where there are no
> requests in a given pool and the resources configured to the pool
> can be freed up for other pools.

Lastly, the documentation mentions extreme cases of pool configuration and calls this out:

> All pools have zero minimums. All the pools compete for available resources and their final sizes are based on resource consumption in each pool. Other factors such as policies play a role in shaping the final pool size.

Is that an accurate summation of the proposed pool configuration I have screencapped above?  Hypothetically, this pool configuration would then allow the server to max out CPU and not meter CPU utilization as I intend, correct?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Question 1

> Do user defined resource pools consider the default pool in their
> calculations?

Yes, they do. You can verify it by editing the minimum CPU for the `default` pool and trying to add another pool later that exceeds the sum of 100. If you tried, you should see the error *Sum of the minimum CPU percentages must not exceed 100*:

[image: Error message regarding Minimum CPU%]

Just be careful if you decide to use this pool in production with a configuration different from the default one as it receives **all** the process that was not specified to another existing pool.

### Question 2

> Is it nonsensical as I believe for the SUM of all calculated shared %
> to be >100%? The MS examples all fall below 100%.

There's a difference between the `MIN%` and the `Calculated Shared %` concepts regarding the Resource Pool:

- The `MIN%` is an amount of CPU that once you define for a pool, it's
  not gonna be available for any other. So, if you define 5 for **Pool
  B**, you only have 95 that can be used for other pools. Those 5 won't
  be shared. That sum is calculated among all existing pools.
- The `Calculated Shared %` is the difference between the `MIN%` and
  the `MAX%` on the same pool, not among all existing pools as above.
  **Pool B** was defined with a `MAX%` of 10, then you have to subtract 5 (the amount it won't share with anyone) from 10 (the max amount of
  CPU it's supposed to use **if** available and not required from some
  other pool).

### Question 3

> Could someone please explain this blurb on shared % from the MS docs,
> I'm not fully understanding what the shared % calculation is supposed
> to represent:

It's related to what I said before: the `MIN%` value states how much CPU a pool owns and won't borrow to any other pool even if it's not processing anything and the 5%  CPU is idle while the whole instance is on peak time consuming 95% and starving for 5% more. Share on the context of that excerpt means the difference between the `MIN%` and the `MAX%` of the same pool. That's why **Pool C** can share 50% and it means that if **Pool C** was idle, it would release all the CPU it is allowed to use so that other pools can consume it.

Comment: thanks for the insight!